# Footer links.phtml not appearing on magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, footer

I have a local site on Magento 2.4.4 and I made the footer under footer/links.phtml which works fine.

[image]

but when I upload it to the test server in Magento 2.3.2 it doesn't show
[image]

what could be the issue? Does Magento 2.3.2 have a different file structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version issue and now resolved. I needed to use the xml template from 2.3.2 instead of 2.4.4